# InsertFeature on a versioned layer [vba]

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vba

I am writing an application that takes data from an Excel Spreadsheet and loads it into an ArcSDE feature class. The Feature class is editable within ArcMap, but I am having trouble inserting a feature with the code.

My code does the following

1. Starts an edit session.

   ```
   Public Sub StartEditing(fctarget)

   Dim peditor As IEditor
   Dim pID    As New UID
   Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
   Dim pDataset As IDataset
   Dim pMap   As IMap
   Dim pmxdoc As IMxDocument
   Dim LayerCount As Integer
   Set pmxdoc = Application.Document
   Set pMap = pmxdoc.FocusMap
   pID = "esriEditor.Editor"
   Set peditor = Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pID)

   If peditor.EditState = esriStateEditing Then Exit Sub

   'Start editing the workspace of teh feature layer
   Set pDataset = fctarget
   MsgBox "Editing: " & pDataset.BrowseName
   peditor.StartEditing pDataset.Workspace

   peditor.StartOperation

   End Sub
   ```
2. Load the data (if it is a new record, the following code runs)

   ```
     If pfeatLayer Is Nothing Then    'if it does not exist - it is new

     'Insert a new record and add new attribute information
     Set pFeatInsertBuf.Shape = pFeat.Shape
     Debug.Print pFeatInsertBuf.Shape.envelope.XMax
     xField = pFeatInsertBuf.Fields.FindFieldByAliasName("ORIG_X")
     yField = pFeatInsertBuf.Fields.FindFieldByAliasName("ORIG_Y")

     pFeatInsertBuf.Value(xField) = pFeat.extent.XMax
     pFeatInsertBuf.Value(yField) = pFeat.extent.YMax

       'Update the attributes
     For C = 1 To NumberOfFields
           If IsNull(pExcelApp.Cells(r, C).Value) Then
               pFeatInsertBuf.Value(C).Value = ""
           Else
               pFeatInsertBuf.Value(C) = pExcelApp.Cells(r, C).Value
           End If
    Next C
    Debug.Print pFeatInsertBuf.Fields.FieldCount
    Debug.Print pFeatInsertBuf.Value(2)
    Debug.Print pFeatInsertCur.Fields.FieldCount
    'store the record
    pFeatInsertCur.InsertFeature pFeatInsertBuf ' #######INSERT THE FEATURE######
    Print #1, "Row number " & r & ": " & "inserted"
    Debug.Print "Row number " & r & ": " & "inserted"
   ```
3. When it has gone through the rest of the spreadsheet, the stop editing process is called and the editor session is closed.

   ```
   Public Sub stopSaveEdits(step As String)

   Dim lngCityDevRefVal As Long

   Dim peditor As IEditor
   Dim pID    As New UID
   Dim lngSave As Integer
   Dim pMap   As IMap
   Dim pmxdoc As IMxDocument
   ' get the current map document and create and editor object
   Set pmxdoc = ThisDocument
   Set pMap = pmxdoc.FocusMap
   pID = "esriEditor.Editor"
   Set peditor = Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pID)
   'step = "Save"
   If peditor.EditState = esriStateEditing Then
       'lngSave = MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo, "Save data")
       If step = "Save" Then
           peditor.StopOperation "Saving..."
           Exit Sub
       ElseIf step = "SaveStop" Then
           peditor.StopOperation "Saving..."

           If peditor.HasEdits = True Then
               peditor.StopEditing True
               'MsgBox "Changes have been saved"

               Exit Sub
           End If
       Else
           peditor.AbortOperation
           'peditor.StopOperation "Saving..."
           peditor.StopEditing False
           MsgBox "Changes have not been saved"
       End If
   End If

   End Sub
   ```

The problem is that the new feature never gets inserted, even though i have specified to do it. Has anyone got any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Note - Using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1, ArcSDE is 9.2

Thanks!

Comment: How did you create pFeatInsertCur? If you create with "useBuffering" options yes, then , you need to write IFeatureCursor::Flush method at last.

Comment: Your code is not showing the full story, how is the FeatureBuffer created?

Comment: @Darksanta, the pFeatInsertCur was set to true, I set it to false (and in the mean time upgraded ArcSDE to 9.3.1) and it now works.